# React Native error Unable to extract native debug metadata

Tags: react-native, crash, apk

I'm using react-native v0.65.1 and received a lot of errors when generating apk

```js
> Task :app:extractReleaseNativeSymbolTables

Unable to extract native debug metadata from D:\REACT NATIVE\test-app\test\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libbetter.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from D:\REACT NATIVE\test-app\test\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libc++_shared.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from D:\REACT NATIVE\test-app\test\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libfabricjni.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from D:\REACT NATIVE\test-app\test\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libfb.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from D:\REACT NATIVE\test-app\test\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libfbjni.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from D:\REACT NATIVE\test-app\test\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libfolly_futures.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from D:\REACT NATIVE\test-app\test\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libfolly_json.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from D:\REACT NATIVE\test-app\test\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libglog.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from D:\REACT NATIVE\test-app\test\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libglog_init.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from D:\REACT NATIVE\test-app\test\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libhermes-executor-common-debug.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.
```

It is very long but I shorten it as it is all about `arm64-v8a ABI`. When I installed the generated APK and opened it, it was closing instantly. Have no idea what's going on as the development didn't have any error.

Been researching for 2 days now but still I cannot find anything that can solve this issue. Looking forward to your help. Thank you!

Comment: if you use MS appcenter sdk - it will capture the crashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find the cause of this issue. I opened my project using android studio (just open the android folder only) and tried running it from there and the emulator was showing

> Unable to load script. Make sure you’re either running a Metor service (run ‘react-native start’) or that your bundle ‘index.android.bundle’ is packaged correctly for release.

P/S: The error above didn't show up when I do `npx react-native run-android`.

Found this very helpful article [React Native: Unable to load script: index. android.bundle](https://medium.com/geekculture/react-native-unable-to-load-script-index-android-bundle-d37eb0b65816)

What I did was, in the `app/build.gradle` there is this line `project.ext.react` and added `bundleInRelease: true` since I want to generate a released APK. And simply run `gradlew assembleRelease` from the android folder.

Comment: this not solved problem with js bundle, but this did: https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/38#issuecomment-721764120

Answer (score 9):

Had this problem myself, and eventually figured out it was because I didn't hook up the "NDK" correctly.

Steps taken to fix it:

1. Android Studio > Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools > Select and install "NDK (Side by side)"
   This may not be necessary if there is already a version of NDK installed locally. Usually in `~/Android/Sdk/ndk/<versionNumber>/`
2. In the project, within the file `/android/build.gradle`, set `ndkVersion` to the right version:

   ```
   buildscript {
       ext {
           // ...
           ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        }
   }
   ```